# Как добавить `target="_blank"` во все ссылки, которые подходят под условие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пробую в расширении для Youtube после загрузки страницы добавить `target="_blank"` во все ссылки, которые подходят под условие `a[href^="/watch?v="]`. Не получается. Что я делаю не так?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="/watch?v="]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
});
```

PS: задача возникла как альтернатива [этой проблеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1484063/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-location-href), которую не удалось решить

Comment: `^=` ищет атрибуты `начинающиеся` с заданной строки, предполагаю что ссылка содержит полный URL и надо использовать `a[href*="/watch?v="]`, то есть атрибут `href` `содержит` заданную строку.

Comment: Там в ссылках не полный адрес. Но не в этом проблема, скрипт не исполняется. Может я его написал с ошибками или я еще чего то не понимаю.

Comment: @Юра нужно всё это в `MutationObserver`.